# Strom ClassNotFoundException when submitting to remote cluster

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, apache-storm

I have a pretty simple topology:

```
builder.setSpout("StreamSpout", new StreamSpout(), 1);
builder.setBolt("Bolt", new TestBolt(), 1).shuffleGrouping("StreamSpout");
```

StreamSpout:

```
public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
    this.outputCollector = collector;
    this.config = conf;
    this.context = context;
}


public void nextTuple() {
    this.outputCollector.emit(new Values("test"));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
}
```

TestBolt:

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    String word = input.getStringByField("word");
    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()).info(word);
}
```

And i submit it using the following code:

```
conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "W.X.Y.Z"); // Cluster's IP
conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT,6627);
conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_PORT,2181);
System.setProperty("storm.jar", "/home/.../{FileName}-SNAPSHOT.jar"); // Generated JAR file path
StormSubmitter submitter = new StormSubmitter();
submitter.submitTopology("de-linkS", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

But whenever i try to submit my topology to my cluster i get the following error from the worker log files:

```
    2015-04-06 21:36:03 b.s.d.worker [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: upa.pfe.storm.spouts.StreamSpout
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:95) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.getSetComponentObject(Utils.java:235) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.task$get_task_object.invoke(task.clj:73) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
...
```

However everything works perfectly when submitting the topology to local cluser.

Any ideas to what i might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured it out!

The problem seems to be in the project's pom.xml file. The pom file was missing the required plugins that:

> create a jar file suitable for deployment to a cluster.

I was able to package and deploy my project using the following pom file as a base for mine: https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/pom.xml

A dumb way to get into truble, but i hope that this thread can be of help and insight to others.

Thank you